# Does a schema for defining Bluetooth Low-Energy GATT services exist?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

The Bluetooth SIG website hosts [several](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) descriptions of standard services that Bluetooth Low-Energy devices could implement.  It provides this description in a human readable format, but also implies that there is a machine-readable version of these schemas called "GATT XML".  I cannot find the specification for GATT XML anywhere -- does it exist?  If not, is there another format for BLE service schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does in fact exist. The XML schema is available for download here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/schema

Comment: that web page does not return an XML schema today, just a list of token names and the last date those tokens were changed. Perhaps the XML schema has moved? Could you possibly post a copy here or a new link?